# Constructing the support of a Borel measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

From Rudin, Real and Complex Analysis, Chapter 8, Problem 7, 1st Edition.

Suppose $E$ is a compact set in $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ without isolated points. Show that $E$ is the support of a continuous positive Borel measure $\mu$. If $m(E)=0$, this gives examples of singular measures.

I am wondering how to prove this. For a classical Cantor set or even fat Cantor set, I know how to construct the measure; for similar fractal shapes analgous methods are possible. However if we only know $E$ is closed and bounded, every point is a limit point of $E$, then I am at a loss how to prove this fact.

Dimension is a barrier. Locally $E$ can be both "continuous" like closed cubes, or "discrete" like fat cantor sets. In the one dimensional case, constructing a sequence of continuous Borel measures via characteristic functions and taking the limit is usually suffice; in the general $\mathbb{R}^{k}$ case, I do not know what canonical choices I have, even though measure - function relationship still preserves.

Comment: You can take a dense subset of $E$ to construct a sequence of measures that converges to a measure with support $E$ in the weak*-topology.

Comment: But how I know the measure I get the "dense subset of $E$" is continuous in the first place?

Comment: I think the following works: Pick an enumeration of $E$ and let $\mu_n$ be the uniform distribution over the first $n$ points in the enumeration.

Comment: This should work only if $E$ is countable.

Comment: Sorry, I meant an enumeration of a dense subset.

Comment: This should work, let me think about it. Thanks.